# Where to store files

Tags: ios, swift

I'm newbee at IOS Developing and just started learning Swift.

In my app I need to store files somewhere...
For example in Android I use assets folder. In IOS I didn't find any way to retrieve folders and files from assets.
Where should I store files to use them when app is running, and how should I get access to them. Also need to get file/folder names

Comment: Have a look Here : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html

Comment: Effectively, you’re asking how to access files in the application main bundle and how to put them there at build time.  I’ll let others fill in the details, as I’m on an iPad with short time, but that should get you answers.  If you look at the bundle manager docs referenced by Tandel, that’ll be a start.

Comment: For static files which you are adding while making the project, save all images in `Assets` , that is specially made for this purpose, you will need to add 2x and 3x of images there. And for other type of files like .mp3, just create a folder in project and add files to them, just make sure that they are added to project target. :) And for the files you create while the app is working, use Documents folder and for the files which you want to get automatically deleted when user stops the application, then save to temp folder. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you what you mean by "store files", but if you just want to store resource files, like a CSS stylesheet, sound effects etc, you can just drag it into the navigator in Xcode (the left panel). In my project here, I've added a bunch of mp3 files:

[image]

To access these files, you can use the `Bundle` class. It will give you the path to a specific file in string or `URL`.

For example, if you want to store the text in a text file named `text.txt` in a string variable:

```
let contentsOfFile = String(contentsOfFile: 
    Bundle.main.path(forResource: "text", ofType: "txt")!, encoding: .utf8)
```

Comment: How should i retrieve names of files inside programmatically?

Comment: @Sereekjan so you want to get all the file names?

Comment: yeap, including folders inside

Comment: @Sereekjan Well, you can retrieve all the paths of files with a specific extension using `paths`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1413058-paths But if you are just storing resource files you should't need to get all the directory names. So I guess you are not trying to store resource files like I guessed. If that's the case, I recommend using the `FileManager` class like Rashwan L said in his answer.

Answer (score -1):

1. use Bundle. In this way, the file will be packaged into the App
2. use Sandbox. This way the file is stored on the local disk